# pdf not responsive when getting multiple pages in it using savefig

Tags: python-3.x

I am using matplotlib pyplot to generate plots. I want all my plots to come in a single pdf so I am using PdfPages. I am able to generate a single pdf with multiple plots but when the number of pages increase in the pdf it takes time to respond,.i.e, It opens and displays the first page of the pdf but when I try scrolling to go to other pages I have to wait for some time to see all the pages. The code I used is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9))

ax = plt.subplot(121)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
dataframe.plot.scatter(x=numericColumn2, y=numericColumn1, ax = ax) 

plt.close()
pdf.savefig()
pdf.close()
```

Is there some parameter or something else I can add so that pdf does not takes time o respond?